# Can I make an online survey in Shiny in which each input depends on the preceding one?

Tags: r, shiny, survey

I am new to shiny and I was wondering whether it is possible to create a kind of online survey with Shiny. Moreover, I would like to evaluate each question and ask the next questions based on this result. At last, I would like to save all the results.

1. Is this possible?
2. Do you know any similar projects that would be a good start

Thank you!

Comment: 1. yes, 2. no. What have you tried?

Comment: @ cory Thanks for the fast reply. Not much actually. I did the tutorial on http://shiny.rstudio.com/. However, I couldn't figure out how I can do the following: 1. Choose an input (not output) conditional on another input and 2. Save all input data. In my framework, I basically do not want to show any output anymore.

Comment: You want http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html. That said, survey logic is kind of a pain in Shiny (you'd have to explicitly code every possible path the user could take). If you can, I would suggest using a Google form (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en) with skip logic